# GPO to configure open file explorer to in windows 10

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We are currently running windows server 2012 R2.

We have upgraded computer to windows 10 and we wish to configure the setting **Open file explorer to** from GPO. We would like the file explorer open to **This PC** insted of **Quick access**. You can see wich setting on this image :
(first setting on general tabs)

http://cdn2.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/folder-options-windows-10-file-explorer.png

How can I configure this setting from GPO?

**EDIT :**

For now we are going to apply a registry modification using group policy editor. But a real GPO or GPP will be better if it's possible.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

LaunchTo DWORD

1 = This PC
2 = Quick access
```

Comment: Have you looked to see if a GPO setting exists for that?

Comment: Yes under user preference they have folder option like hide extention or hide hidden folder but this settings is not there.

Comment: Then you'll need to download the Windows 10 Group Policy Templates. I'm down voting your question because you could have easily figured this out for yourself. - http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2015/08/07/windows-10-group-policy-admx-templates-now-available-for-download.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a group policy setting for this, so you will need to use a User Registry Group Policy Preference.

If you want it to behave like a traditional Registry group policy, you may want to consider checking the box for "remove this item when it no longer applies".  If you want it to apply only to Windows 10, you may want to consider applying the following WMI filter or WMI item level target:

```
SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Caption LIKE "Microsoft Windows 10%"
```